# for looping in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

in my php I have such code in a while loop...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wallpost ORDER BY wallpostid DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$rate = "<div class=\"example-".$id." \" data-postid=\"".$id."\"></div></br>Post id: <span class=\"example-rating-".$id."\">".$id."</span>";
}
```

jquery is...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[class^="example-"]').not('[class^="example-rating-"]').ratings(3).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
var child = $(this).find('[class^="example-rating-"]');
child.text(data.rating);

$.post('count.php', {
     rate: data.rating,
     wallpostid: jQuery(this).data("postid")
}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
});
```

for the value A I get the null value, but if i replace

```
var a = $('.example-rating-50').html();  //let say the wallpostid is 50
```

it only can pass the value 50 to count.php
If now let say I have 2 wallpostid which is 22 and 50 (loop it with while loop )
if I rate wallpostid is 22 then I want pass the value of $id=22 from php to jquery and $.post to count.php. Do the same this if I rate wallpostid=50.

Comment: Every time one says jQuery when meaning javascript actually - a kitten dies :-(

Comment: What's with concatenating an empty string after `i`? It's not the problem, just weird

Comment: you don't need a for loop, you can iterate over a set of jquery objects using `.each()`

Comment: In the above code your `var a = $('.example-rating-50').html();` is just equal to `50` which is just `i` so why bother? you can also use `.text()` or `.val()` to get to the value.  Beyond that I am unsure there is a point to this question, perhaps you could clarify the desired results and post more specific to that.

Comment: Why does everyone generate mounds of HTML within PHP and then nest quotes so they need escaping?! `$rate = sprintf('<div class="example-%1$d"></div><br>Post id: <span class="example-rating-%1$d">%1$d</span>', $id)` is so much more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a for loop in the javascript, there are selectors that can handle this, for instance `class^=`

**PHP**

```
$rate = "<div class=\"example-".$id." \" data-postid=\"".$id."\"></div></br>Post id: <span class=\"example-rating-".$id."\">".$id."</span>";
```

**JS**

```
//Find elements that have class starting with 'example-' but Not example-rating- 
$('[class^="example-"]').not('[class^="example-rating-"]').ratings(3).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
    //Find Child element that has class starting with 'example-rating-'
    var child = $(this).find('[class^="example-rating-"]');
    child.text(data.rating);

    $.post('count.php', {
         rate: data.rating,
         wallpostid: jQuery(this).data("postid")
    }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur response, i try the code already but the wallpost id come out NULL....

Comment: @user2374946 because in your code you have it setting data.rating to the example-rating and then calling .html() on the same element and using that as wallpostid, so basically you are using html code as your wallpostid and your php code is more than likely filtering it out as its not an id. See edit, added the use of data-* attributes to get the id for wallpostid.

Comment: wallpostid get undefined....
If u doing this star rating system, How u can get the wallpostid and how many star the user rate? Can u show me ur code? hehe^^

Comment: if you are getting `undefined` then you probably didnt edit your php code to add `data-postid` attribute in the `example` div element, what your php code should look like is in my answer already.

Comment: I copy the syntax which u give me. yup, I can get the wallpostid but always get the biggest 1. Let say I have 22 and 50 wallpostid, when I rate wallpostid = 22 ,it cant get 22 but is 50.

Comment: please reedit your question to show what you are currently using for your php code and the javascript

Comment: You have not updated your question to contain the newly edited code that you are testing out. Its the same php and javascript that was there when you first posted the question. We need to see your changes that you have made to it. For instance we have suggested that you use the right kind of selectors instead of using the for loop in the javascript but the current code in your question still shows the for loop and the selectors you were using before.

Answer (score 4):

it is a problem with the closure variable `i`

Since you are using `i` inside the callback, it will have the last value from the loop which is 102 that is why it is failing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        (function(idx){
            $('.example-' + idx + '').ratings(3).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
                $('.example-rating-' + idx + '').text(data.rating);
                var a = $('.example-rating-' + idx + '').html();

                $.post('count.php', {
                    rate: data.rating,
                    wallpostid: a
                }, function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
            });
        })(i)
    }
});
```

a better solution could be

```
$rate = "<div class=\"examples example-".$id." \" data-idx=\"".$id"\"></div></br>Post id: <span class=\"example-rating-".$id."\">".$id."</span>";
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.examples').ratings(3).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
        var i = $(this).data('idx')
        var a = $('.example-rating-' + i + '').text(data.rating);

        $.post('count.php', {
            rate: data.rating,
            wallpostid: data.rating
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: you're first selector, in the second code, will also select the child `example-rating-*` elements

Comment: Better yet, use `data-`attributes instead of parsing classes, and use classes that you can actually match directly

Comment: @JanDvorak yes... i removed that ... for now

Comment: @ArunPJohny, thank for ur response, can u explain to me, why need 2 $(document).ready(function () { }??
and i try the code u given to me, when I rate a wallpost,the wallpost id then equal to the star I rate but not the wallpost.

Comment: @user2374946 those are two different solutions

Comment: @user2374946 can you share which is the ratings plugin used

Comment: oic, but get the same result, mean when i rate 2 star the wallpost id become 2...

Comment: for the second solution, the wallpostid: data.rating ? Not wallpostid: a ??

Answer (score 0):

I like to not build element selectors dynamically.

```
var $examples = $('[class^=example-]:not([class^=example-rating])');
var $ratings = $('[class^=example-rating]');

$examples.ratings(3).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
  var index = $examples.index(this);
  var $rating = $ratings.eq(index);
  $rating.text(data.rating);
  var a = $rating.attr('class').split('-')[2];

  $.post('count.php', {
    rate: data.rating,
    wallpostid: a
  }, function (data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur response, i have try ur code, but when i rate 1 star for a wallpost, the value come out is 1 but not the wallpost id....

Comment: Well, are you changing the contents of the `.example-rating-x`?  If so, try parsing the class name.  I updated the code.

Comment: thank for the updated code, but the wllpost id it will be the biggest no I got.Let say i have 2 wallpost id ,22 and 50, when i rate wallpostid=50 is ok, but i rate the wallpostid=22, the wallpost id still the 50, the biggest 1...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Let say I have 2 wallpost id in the php, 22 and 50. I try the code above which only can get the biggest number wallpost id which is 50 although I rate at wallpostid of 22. Can u get what I mean?